# Sequential-based function, used to replace sequence in another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

The day before yesterday I encountered a problem in Excel, which I didn't know how to solve using manually the inbuilt Excel features, hence today I started learning VBA. The problem is : in one of the worksheets, say **Worksheet2**, I'm given a sequence (5 consecutive cells) of length 5, consisting of 3 different characters (to be more concrete I'm given around 1k+ sequences, but that's not the issue). In another worksheet, say **Worksheet1**, I'm given again a sequence of length 5 (again, 5 consecutive cells), consisting of the same 3 characters, which by the other hand is being used to calculate an coefficient, which is being calculated in a 3rd sheet - **Worksheet3**, which varies upon the respective sequence.

What I want to do: on **Worksheet2** I want to write a function that takes the respective sequence, replaces it into **Worksheet1** and returns the respective coefficient. E.g. the sequence in **Worksheet2** is ABBAS, I initiate the next cell of the sequence with =Calc_Coeff(A;B;B;A;S), which returns the coefficient, which is being calculated in **Worksheet3**. What I tried to do is:

```
Function Calc_Coeff(One As String, Two As String, Three As String, Four As String, Five As String) As Double

Dim Base As Worksheet, Distr As Worksheet

Set Base = Sheets("Worksheet1")
Set Distr = Sheets("Worksheet3")
Base.Cells(2, 3).Value = One
Base.Cells(2, 4).Value = Two
Base.Cells(2, 5).Value = Three
Base.Cells(2, 6).Value = Four
Base.Cells(2, 7).Value = Five

Calc_Coeff = Distr.Cells(68, 8).Value
End Function
```

When passing the functions with the respective sequence it returns #VALUE!, for some unknown to me reason. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Look up differences between a Sub and a Function. A function returns a value only to the cell in which it is located. You are trying to use a function to alter the contents of multiple cells

Comment: Hello! That's exactly what I'm aiming for - exactly returning the value in the cell, whilst altering those cells. Maybe I could nest the Sub into the function, although from what I've read that's not possible in VBA.

Comment: Not to do what you want.  You could write a SUB.  Or you could have your function return a horizontal array of values.  How to enter it into the worksheet depends on your version of Excel.  It later versions, it will `Spill`.  In earlier versions you can either enter it as an array formula; or use the `INDEX` function to extract the individual elements.

Comment: Also, if you haven't already, navigate to Tools/Options/General and select the option to `Require Variable Declaration`. This will place `Option Explicit` at the top of any newly created module (and you can add it to existing modules). It will save you a lot of time by catching typos and other errors, as well as other benefits.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I understand everything you're saying. I wrote a Sub that's supposed to change the cells in **Worksheet 1** with the argument's that I'm passing it with (the 5 strings), then I'm calling it in the function and returning the coefficient in the end. The #VALUE! appears exactly when I'm changing the characters, e.g. in Base.Cells(2, 3).Value = One (I haven't fixed it yet). Do I have to navigate it to the worksheet before executing the code or?

Comment: It sounds like you are calling the Sub with a Function that is on the worksheet. That won't work for what you seem to want. You will need to write the whole thing as a Sub, and then trigger it, perhaps with a button, writing the values and the coefficient to the appropriate cells.  Or have two functions; the first returning an array of values, and the second dependent on that array to calculate your coefficient.

Comment: Your `Calc_Coeff` writes to cells.  When called as a UDF, a Function can't do that, hence the error.  FYI there are workarounds for this, but I'd reccomend first try to redesign your Workbook to avoid the need

Comment: Alright, so apparently that's the problem - function cannot write into cells. I, apparently, cannot call the sub into the function either. Perhaps, as @RonRosenfield suggested, I should trigger it with a button? I honestly don't know, I tried and failed. Could you provide such a workaround? Thank you.